# JDBC does not work with WHERE clause

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

I implemented a remote query tool via `JDBC` and `SpringBoot`, and it works with simple `SQL`:

```
curl http://192.168.x.x:XXXX/etl/sql?sql=select%20room_id,name%20from%20dim.dim_room%20limit%2010
```

The `SQL` sent in the `GET` request:

```
select room_id,name from dim.dim_room limit 10
```

This returns expected result, but if I add `where` clause:

```
curl http://192.168.x.x:xxxx/etl/sql?sql=select%20room_id,name%20from%20dim.dim_room%20where%20room_id%3D19569
```

The `SQL` sent in the `GET` request:

```
select room_id,name from dim.dim_room where room_id = 19569
```

It returns exception (The SQL can run correctly in my `Hive2`):

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:296)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:392)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HivePreparedStatement.executeQuery(HivePreparedStatement.java:109)
        at com.lz.model.ETLEntity.query(ETLEntity.java:59)
        at com.lz.service.impl.ETLServiceImpl.executeShellScript(ETLServiceImpl.java:19)
        at com.lz.web.action.etl.ETLController.identify(ETLController.java:36)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Why could this happen and how to resolve it?

---

`SQL` shown in the log is correct:
[image]

Comment: @AxelH yes, the type of `room_id` is `int`.

Comment: please check room_id  is a valid column name and the type is integer. Mostly likely this happens because your where clause column expecting a  String but you are passing a integer . or vise versa

Comment: @Optimuskck thx for your reply, but the data type of `room_id` is integer..

Comment: this will help https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/69760/hive-query-with-where-clasue-throwing-error-using.html

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal you should post an answer explaining what you found in that comment, this could be interesting !

Comment: You don't need to blank out `192.168.x.x:XXXX`. It's your local network, none of us have access there :)

Comment: @AxelH i have never worked on hive. I just tried to find the issue on google and I found this. So I just put it as a comment thinking that it might help :)

Comment: @SuperDelta can you show me the connection object you are creating?

Comment: @AxelH Thx for your help man, I've done that but the SQL shown in the log seems correct...

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal Thx for your reply. I just added the pic at the end of my question.

Comment: @SuperDelta pass the username also to the connection and then try it

Comment: Can you post the hive  server2 log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`DriverManager.getConnection(String, String, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and pass a valid user and password to get a connection that grand you access to the server

Like we can see in [that page](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/69760/hive-query-with-where-clasue-throwing-error-using.html), Hive don't need user identification for simple queries but does when you add a condition, a condition requires more processing that need identitication

> Running `SELECT * FROM <table>` does not need to start a job and that's why SquirreL can run this query using JDBC only without any issue. But, for running a query like `SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <condition>` needs to start a map/reduce job, which, further needs a linux and hadoop account in the cluster
>
> Answer by Manish Gupta

Comment: @AxelH That's it! This problem resolved! Thx for your help!